# A-Level Physics: What is the current needed to maintain the wire at a steady temperature of 387∘C?

Tags: power, current, temperature, ohms-law

I am stuck on answering an A Level physics question:

**When a current of 5.00A flows through a tungsten wire in a stream of air at 27.0∘C, the wire attains a steady temperature of 57.0∘C. It may be assumed that the wire's resistance is proportional to absolute temperature (i.e. temperature measured from absolute zero at −273∘C) and that the rate the wire loses heat energy is proportional to the temperature difference between the wire and the air stream.**

What is the current needed to maintain the wire at a steady temperature of 387∘C?

The question gives two equations:

**V = I R** and **P = V I**

And in the text tells us:

Resistance of Wire = k * -273

Rate of wire loosing heat energy = k * temperature difference between the wire and the air stream. 
So the higher the temperature, the more current that is needed to maintain the temperature.

But I cannot see how these equations can be used with the information given.

Thank you for any help as I am extremely stuck.

Comment: There are a number of other equations given in the English text of the problem. Start by writing the two sentences after "It may be assumed" as equations. Another critical piece of information for all exam questions: how many marks are assigned to the answer?

Comment: What can you assume about the power needed to develop a temperature difference between the wire and the airstream? What conditions are needed to give a suitable power at that temperature?

Comment: @pjc50 The question has been adapted from a test and has no assigned mark. Is it telling us that the wires resistance = |-273 - 57| (for when the temperature of the wire is 57 degrees Celsius or that the Resistance of the wire is a variable times the constant of -273)? Thanks for the help

Comment: Convert 57C to kelvin by subtracting -273 => 330K. The wire's resistance is proportional to this, so $$R_1 = 330 \alpha$$ You can use that to determine R_2 as a multiple of alpha at the higher temperature. Rearrange the other equations to get P=I^2 R. You now need to get two equations for the power dissipated to the air at the various temperatures (relative to the air this time, not absolute zero). Keep eliminating variables until you find an answer.

Comment: @pjc50 I found that R_2 = 2 R_1 as R_2 = 660α. Then if I know that P = 25 * 330 /alpha but to find alpha I would need P. Is there anyway I can convert the temperature to a measurement of power? I could convert the temperature relative to air being 30 degrees Celsius but to joules but then I need the time it took for the rise to get power. Maybe I could eliminate this with the time from the current?

Comment: It's a steady-state model, there's no time component. Have you converted "the rate the wire loses heat energy is proportional to the temperature difference between the wire and the air stream" to an equation yet? Hint: what is the unit of rate of heat *energy* loss?

Comment: Is there any way I can convert the temperature to a measurement of power? You have to make an assumption about how those two are linked, and then put them into an equation.

Comment: https://isaacphysics.org/questions/heating_a_wire - check your answer here - I calculated 12.25A but I got it wrong! Actually I can prove I got it right but they were asking for 1 dp and rounding down!

Comment: The unit of heat energy loss is power? As its energy / time. So we know that P = k * the difference is wire temp. So for the first example where the difference in temperature is 30 degrees Celsius. Then P = k * 30. We calculated P using Alpha before so: 25 * 330α = k * 30

Comment: For the example we are trying to find current for the temperature difference is 360 degrees Celsius. Therefore I^2 * 660α = k * 360. Then I rearranged to set both equations to α and cancel it out. Then managed to cancel K from both sides to get I = around 1723 which I have a feeling is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint 1:

You have two scenarios; one at 57 degC and one at 387 degC. You need to find an expression (of something) that has the same *meaning* at both temperatures then you can equate those two expressions.

I've got the right answer BTW so what can you say about the power lost as heat at 57 degC and the power lost as heat at 387 degC?

Hint 2 (some time later):

You should equate watts per degree centigrade at both temperatures - derive a (fairly) simple formula that gives you watts per degree C - this is constant for both scenarios.

Comment: I used the constant to show the proportionality between the resistance and the temperature in Kelvin and set those equal to each other. I used alpha to be the proportionality constant for the resistance. We know that: R of the 57 C wire = 330α and R of the 387 C wire = 660α from the other proportionality relationship in the question we know that P = 30k as the rate of loss of energy (P) is proportional with the constant K to the difference in temperature between the air and the wire.

Comment: We can then use P = I^2 R then re arrange for α to get α = 30k / 8250 and α = 360k / I^2 * 660  then also know that P = 360k for the 387 C wire. Then use P = I^2 R then re arrange for α to get α = 30k / 8250 and α = 360k / I^2 * 660 then rearrange to get I, Does that sound like the right track?

Comment: Scenario 1: watts / deg = 25\$R\$/30. Scenario 2: watts per degree = \$I^2\cdot 2R\$/360. Equate them and you find that R cancels leaving I = 12.2 amps

Answer (score 0):

More hints:

You know that at 5 amps the wire stays 30 C above ambient. You don't know the wire resistance, so let's just call it R0, and the power dissipated P0. Now, how much power will you need to get your 387? What does this say about the new wire resistance?

Comment: That it is double the Resistance of the wire that stays 30C above ambient

Comment: @PeterWalkington - Please. Answer the question(s). What power is needed? If the resistance has doubled, how much does the current have to change to get that power? Does this answer the question?

Comment: P = I^2 R If R doubles then I^2 has to half. So I is multiplied by 1 / sqrt(2) ?

Comment: Try again. To repeat myself - answer the question. "What power is needed?" It takes more power to keep something hot. How much?  Start by looking at the temperature requirement as the wire loses heat to the air. How much more power is needed keep the wire at 387?